# Dealing with WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions When scraping a website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape an aspx website showing a list of search results using selenium; when the script 'clicks' a button an alert pops up - I tried 'clicking' the alert-button to continue to the next page using `EC.alert_is_present` but it raised an `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` error.

Looking at the code of the button itself using 'inspect element shows:

```
<a onclick="WaitPlease('_ctl0_btnDownloadWordDocs');
if (ConfirmWordDocDownload()==false) return false;"
```

`id="_ctl0_btnDownloadWordDocs" class="ButtonsMedium" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("_ctl0:btnDownloadWordDocs", "", true, "", "",false, true)) onclicksaved="function onclick(event){  WaitPlease('_ctl0_btnDownloadWordDocs');`

```
if(ConfirmWordDocDownload()==false) return false;}">...</a>
```

My guess it has something to do with the `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` right after the `href` but googling didn't get me any reference to this situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same error. 
But with jQuery o javascript is not necessary to execute from selenium the onClick content, just use jQuery or javascript -> to make click in the element.

```
String onClick = "$('#_ctl0_btnDownloadWordDocs').click();";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
js.executeAsyncScript(onClick);
```

Some update about time out.

```
try {
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(500,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    String onClick = "$('#MainContent_btnConsultar').click();";
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
    js.executeAsyncScript(onClick);
} catch (ScriptTimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope this resolve your error as mine.
Maybe you must to update from Java to Python

Imports you need

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.ScriptTimeoutException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```